# Error for version of mysqlclient still appears, after delete if check from base.py?

Tags: python, django

OK, I have this error, like many others before me, I tried everyhing I found at google, more than 3 hours and nothing. I also install newer version but still appers, probably should I refresh packages or ?

**Error:**

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

**Also delete if check from `base.py` in:**

```
if version < (1, 3, 13):
```

> path_to_projectLib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py

First I tried with `pass` .. then delete whole if check, but still appers? From where it comes ?

EDIT (result from `pip freeze`) command:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.7
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==2.2.4
django-allauth==0.39.1
gevent==1.4.0
gevent-eventemitter==2.1
greenlet==0.4.15
idna==2.8
mysql-connector-python==8.0.17
mysqlclient==1.4.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
protobuf==3.9.1
pycparser==2.19
pylibscrypt==1.8.0
PyMySQL==0.9.3
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.2
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
steam==0.9.1
toolz==0.10.0
urllib3==1.25.3
vdf==3.2
```

Comment: How you installed newer version and did you uninstall older before it?

Comment: @ErHarshRathore `pip uninstall mysqlclient` ->> `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have both mysqlclient and PyMySQL intalled? I was having the same problem. When I did a pip freeze I had the following installed.

mysqlclient==1.4.4

PyMySQL==0.9.3

I uninstalled PyMySQL, made sure the references to it were gone from __ init__.py and then all worked properly for me.

Comment: Well.. after uninstall PyMySQL it works fine, but I'm curious why it works at other computer with PyMySQL.. the difference is I use XAMPP here